# Term Aggregation on one field and getting multiple fields as output

Tags: elasticsearch, group-by, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to do term aggregation one field and I want multiple fields as output along with the key on which the term aggregation is done. Similar to

`SELECT COUNT(FIELD1), FIELD2, FIELD3 FROM TABLE GROUP BY FIELD1`

I tried sub aggregations something similar to this

```
"aggs": {
   "agg_name": {
       "terms": {
          "field": "FIELD1",
            "order": {
              "_count": "desc"
            }
          }, 
          "aggs": {
            "agg_name": {
              "top_hits": {
                "_source": {
                  "includes": ["FIELD2", "FIELD3"]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

But result is listed only upto top_hits

Comment: SELECT COUNT(FIELD1), FIELD2, FIELD3 FROM TABLE GROUP BY FIELD1 is not correct. We usually build aggregation like this: SELECT FIELD1, count(FIELD2), sum(FIELD3) FROM TABLE GROUP BY FIELD1

Comment: Thanks @Mathew for your comment. My use case is different, I'm not able to put that properly over here. But I found my solution.